# A formula to determine the number in a given sequence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, calendar-computations

I'm working with some specific numbers concerning a calendar calculation.
Basically, 13 years in a sequence correspond to 13 different numbers:

| Year | Given number |
| --- | --- |
| Year 1 | 1 |
| Year 2 | 10 |
| Year 3 | 6 |
| Year 4 | 2 |
| Year 5 | 11 |
| Year 6 | 7 |
| Year 7 | 3 |
| Year 8 | 12 |
| Year 9 | 8 |
| Year 10 | 4 |
| Year 11 | 13 |
| Year 12 | 9 |
| Year 13 | 5 |

(And so on... year 14 --- 1, year 15 --- 10, year 16 --- 6).

As you can see, there is a difference of 9 between each number and the next, with the condition that it must not exceed **13** (10 goes to 6 because 10+9= 19 and 19 - **13** = 6 and so on).

I've been trying to find a formula that gives the corresponding number of a given year (e. g. you input **8** and it gives you **12**) but can't seem to find one. I think it is related to modular arithmetic but I'm unfamiliar with it.

What path can you suggest to uncover the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive formula is
$$x_{n+1}=(x_n+9) \ \textrm{mod} \ 13$$

Comment: What happens if I don't know the previous numbers? Is there a way of doing the calculation?

Comment: If $x$ is the year number then your number is the remainder when $9x-8$ is divided by $13$. Except when the remainder is $0$, in which case you take $13$. If that's any help.....

Comment: @PabloIvan you would have infinite solutions for e.g. $1$, but if there was another one even before we can say the solution would be $5$, I guess